# Why don't producers of goods with inelastic demand refuse to increase supply?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, elasticity

I'm reading Paul Samuelson's Economics (19th edition, 2009). In page 71, the Paradox of the Bumper Harvest is introduced. According to the paradox, an increase in food supply from a good harvest actually decreases total revenue for farmers. This happens because food is an inelastic good, so demand does not increase with supply in the same rate. If this is the case, why don't farmers refuse to sell excess supply (for example, by burning excess food), to keep prices up?

Comment: This is why subsidies were created. So that a surplus harvest doesn't lead to a bunch of farmers going out of business, then a famine the next year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because "farmers" as a collective is not a decision maker. Decisions, e.g. on how much food to burn, are made by *individual* farmers. Now an individual farmer, by her own decision, has only negligible influence on the market price. She simply cannot "keep prices up" on her own. Thus, each individual farmer has a strong incentive not to burn any food but to sell everything she produced. So everybody sells whatever they can, and the market price is low. Sadly for them (but luckily for consumers), the farmers are stuck in a sort of prisoner's dilemma.

Answer (score 0):

> why don't farmers refuse to sell excess supply (for example, by burning excess food), to keep prices up?

They **do** refuse to sell crops when prices are low.  In that case, they **store**<sup>1</sup> their crops in silos (in the US and Canada, at least) until commodity prices rise.  That's when they sell.

Of course, sometimes prices don't rise, and at some point they have to sell anyway to pay debts due, buy seed for next year, etc.

<sup>1</sup>Burn??  That stuff cost *money* to grow.  Money that's got to be paid back.  Even selling at a loss brings in *some* money.